# aggregate function not working php codeigniter

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, aggregate, php-7

I wrote a aggregate query to get data in mongodb. same query I need to run via php codigniter,

This is my mongodb query

```
    db.states.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            states: {
                $filter: {
                   input: "$states",
                   as: "state",
                   cond: { $eq: [ "$$state.country_id", "101" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ])
```

same query i need to convert for php codignater. I have used this [library](https://github.com/ehoutsma/Codeigniter-MongoDB) to perform the db operarion.

**I tried:**

```
    $pipeline = [
                  [
                  '$project' => [
                      'states' =>[
                        '$filter' => [
                          'input' => '$states',
                           'as'   => 'state',
                           'cond' => [
                             '$eq' => [
                               '$$state.country_id' => $country_id
                                ]
                            ]
                          ]
                      ]
                  ]
                  ]
              ];
    $result = $this->mongo_db2->aggregate('tb10_states', $pipeline);
```

But, its throw `Message: Unrecognized expression '$$state.country_id'`

Suggest me How to fix this.

Comment: `$$state.country_id` -> `$state.country_id` ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam  mongodb condition to get data `cond: { $eq: [ "$$state.country_id", "101" ] }`

Comment: if you change `$$state.country_id -> $state.country_id` then throw `$state.country_id` error